# AngularJS BootStrap UI-Select - How to change icon on the right

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to set an icon to a ui-select, however I've been failing. I've seen several examples online, where they have screenshots of arrows, or different icons. I'm curious how I can change this out.

Currently, I'm not having much luck, as I don't have any icon showing.

[image]

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="myModel" theme="bootstrap" on-select="myOnSelect()">
```

I assume I'm missing a CSS reference, or something else.

Example I found that has ui-select with arrows: http://embed.plnkr.co/jBJkDb

Looking at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select there is a section called "Examples: Disabling Instead of Removing Selected Items in Multiple Selection" which has a different icon with a different color.

Can someone identify how to change the icon on the right for the ui-select?

Comment: Your plunker link doesn't work

Comment: @jbrown, not my plunker, just what I found. It displays properly on my end.

Comment: can you share plunker of your code?

Comment: After a lot of troubleshooting, I found out that the reason I did not have a down arrow icon on the right is because of the `multiple` attribute that is specified. Modifying the plunker link provided allowed for me to recreate the icon disappearing. Leaving the question open for anyone who can show how to change the icon.

Comment: From what I can tell, it looks like when you have a single that the component is a drop down list, however when you do multiple that it is like an edit box. I created a temporary work around, that creates chevrons that float over the proper position (and are transparent to clicks) and flip up and down, based on the state of the underlying component (e.g. if closed then down chevron, if open then up chevron). I'll wait to see if anyone has a better solution.